# best practice for connecting to windows azure service from corporate environment

Tags: azure

Scenario:
We have web application and services that needs to communicate with applications hosted in azure. Also, somehow developers should be able to deploy the azure applications as well.

Could someone please help me decide or choose the best practices on which is the best way to connect the corporate application to communicate with azure hosted applications?

1. Open firewall for ranges provided by MS (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29840 ) There are lots and security guys don't want to open all.
2. Configure proxy on internal application such that it goes via proxy with service account which has access for requesting 443 and 80.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Azure Service Bus](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/messaging/).

> "Service Bus Relay solves the challenges of communicating between on-premises applications and the outside world by allowing on-premises web services to project public endpoints. Systems can then access these web services, which continue to run on-premises from anywhere on the planet."

Also read [How to Use the Service Bus Relay Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/).

For deployments, we use the Azure Service Management REST API for DEV/TEST deployments directly to Azure via HTTP.  For Production deployments, our builds are setup to upload the  package and config files to a BLOB and our PROD Support team deploys using the Azure Portal from the BLOB files.  You can find the build task code to copy your packages [here](https://github.com/rhysgodfrey/MSBuildAzure), thanks to [Rhys Godfrey](https://github.com/rhysgodfrey).

Comment: Azure Service Bus only partially solves the problem. We need to deploy our application and be able to connect to sql azure, for which 443 port is required.

Comment: SQL is actually on 1433, and deploying your application is via HTTP - you don't have port 80 open?